# delete account also delete answers?

Tags: support, user-accounts

if I delete my account, will this also delete all my answers and activity in the site?

Seems that the body of the question require more text. Well, I will leave this site.

Comment: You may delete your account, but anything else remains, as it is property of Stack Exchange under their license, which you accepted when you created your account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [What EXACTLY happens when I ask to delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131665)  (emphasis mine):

> When you delete an account, the account is anonymized (as above), and **only negatively-scored posts are deleted.** All of your posts (deleted and not) just appear to come from some anonymous user who doesn't have an account anymore.

Also auto-deleting is a bit harsher for questions without owner. From the [Help Center](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) (emphasis mine):

> If the question is more than 365 days old, and has a score of 0 or less, or a **score of 1 and a deleted owner** it will be automatically deleted.

Comment: thanks, I understand that I have to delete manually all my interventions and then proceed to delete my account, thanks!

Comment: well, seems more difficult, since after start to deleting, a sign appears showing: You have deleted 5 of your post, further deleting is blocked. How can I delete all my posts and answers?

Comment: @sergiouribe It's a pity to see you leave. Do you really *want* to delete everything you have written? (Apart from being classified as a form of vandalism on this site.) If your screen handle is your "real name" and you fear any association with the content here to your RL name in the future it might calm you down to know that your screen name will get converted to an anonymous user-number format once your account is deleted?

Comment: @sergiouribe That also means that this user-id is very hard to trace on this site (no user page, no cross links between posts). If my assumptions in the comment above are correct then may I suggest you just rename your account, leave it open, and keep for yourself the ability and possibility to return with all your posts and reputation ready to be picked up were you left?

Comment: @sergiouribe - You will also have difficulty deleting questions which have answers as it protects someone who has spent the time to answer your question.

Comment: thanks for the replies and sorry for the delay, but I was banned and this preventd to post any answer or reply to moderators. All the best.